# Implementing piechart with too many wedges

Tags: analytics, graph

Hello I need to implement a graph/pie chart between Customer support- time to first response of a case VS  severity of the case . Since the time to first response has a lot of values the pie chart has too many wedges to infer anything. Ive tried using bucket fields for time to first respons but due to the limit of the fields being maximum 20 , it says it is too complex and doesnt produce the output. Is there any work around for this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data needs to be made less granular or it will always look like this on a chart. Use a data type that can be grouped, e.g. a `Number` field named `Hours Before First Response`. That could easily be bucketed into digestible chunks and reported upon.